# Get a record of one fields and also of the Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `CountryMaster` and `StatesMaster`. The fields are:

```
CountryMaster(CountryId, Name)

StateMaster(StateId, Name, CountryId)
```

The `StateMaster.CountryId` is a Foreign key. I want to get the `Name` of `States` from `StateMaster` as well as the `Name` of the `Country` to which that State belongs from `CountryMaster`.

I want this in one query.
How can i get this?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
    s.Name AS StateName
    , c.Name AS CountryName
FROM
    dbo.StateMaster s
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CountryMaster c
ON  c.CountryId = s.CountryId
```

> [**Join Fundamentals**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx)
>
> By using joins, you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on
>   logical relationships between the tables. Joins indicate how Microsoft
>   SQL Server should use data from one table to select the rows in
>   another table.
>
> A join condition defines the way two tables are related in a query by:
>
> ```
> Specifying the column from each table to be used for the join. A
> ```
>
> typical join condition specifies a foreign key from one table and its
>   associated key in the other table.
>
> ```
> Specifying a logical operator (for example, = or <>,) to be used
> ```
>
> in comparing values from the columns.
>
> Inner joins can be specified in either the FROM or WHERE clauses.
>   Outer joins can be specified in the FROM clause only. The join
>   conditions combine with the WHERE and HAVING search conditions to
>   control the rows that are selected from the base tables referenced in
>   the FROM clause.